# Definition of the twisted spin covariant derivative for twisted spinor bundles

Tags: riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles, clifford-algebras, spin-geometry, gauge-theory

Let $S\to M$ be the spinor bundle and
\begin{equation}
\nabla^S\colon\Omega^0(M,S)=\Gamma(M,S)\to\Omega^1(M,S)=\Gamma(M,T^*M\otimes S)
\end{equation}
the spin covariant derivative. In addition, let $E\to M$ be a vector bundle with a covariant derivative $\nabla^E\colon\Omega^0(M,E)\to\Omega^1(M,E).$ In some notes I'm reading the twisted spin covariant derivative (used to define the twisted Dirac operator) is defined as
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\nabla:=\nabla^S\otimes 1+1\otimes\nabla^E.
\end{equation}
However, I don't see how the operators $\nabla^S\otimes 1$ and $1\otimes\nabla^E$ are defined, since we can't write
\begin{equation}
\Omega^0(M,S\otimes E)\cong\Omega^0(M,S)\otimes E\cong S\otimes\Omega^0(M,E)
\end{equation}
(these expressions are undefined), unlike for vector valued functions, where
\begin{equation}
C^\infty(M,V\otimes W)\cong C^\infty(M,V)\otimes W\cong V\otimes C^\infty(M,W).
\end{equation}

**Edit**: What about
\begin{equation}
\Omega^0(M,S\otimes E)\cong\Omega^0(M,S)\otimes\Omega^0(M,E)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\Omega^1(M,S\otimes E)\cong\Omega^1(M,S)\otimes\Omega^0(M,E)\cong\Omega^0(M,S)\otimes\Omega^1(M,E)
\end{equation}
If that's correct, I guess I see how $(1)$ would make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every section of $S\otimes E$ is of the form $s\otimes e$ with $s\in \Gamma(S)$ and $e\in \Gamma(E)$. But it locally is a finite sum of such tensor product of sections. That is, if $\gamma \in \Gamma(S\otimes E)$, then, locally:
$$
\gamma = \sum_{i=1}^N s_i\otimes e_i
$$
for $s_i$ local sections of $S$ and $e_i$ local sections of $E$. Hence, we define $\nabla$ as:
$$
\nabla \gamma = \sum_{i=1}^N \left(\nabla^Ss_i\right)\otimes e_i + s_i\otimes \left(\nabla^E e_i\right).
$$
One can show this does not depend on the representatives chosen in a local representation.

In short : $\Gamma(S\otimes E)$ is locally generated by simple tensors $s\otimes e$.

**Comment** In the comments section, there is a "problem": let $f$ be a smooth function and $s \in \Gamma(S)$, $e\in \Gamma(E)$. Write $\tilde{s} = fs$ and $\tilde{e} = fe$. Then $\tilde{s}\otimes e = s \otimes \tilde{e}$, and:
\begin{align}
\nabla\left(\tilde{s}\otimes e\right) &= \left(\nabla^S\tilde{s} \right)\otimes e + \tilde{s}\otimes \nabla^E e \\
&= \left(\mathrm{d}f \otimes s + f\nabla^Ss \right)\otimes e + f s\otimes \nabla^E e \\
&= \mathrm{d}f\otimes s \otimes e + f \left(\nabla^Ss\otimes e + s\otimes\nabla^Ee \right)\\
&= \mathrm{d}f \otimes \left( s\otimes e\right) + f \nabla \left(s\otimes e\right).
\end{align}
The same computations with $\tilde{e}$ show that $\nabla \left(f s\otimes e \right)$ does not depend on where we put $f$ as a coefficient.

Comment: Thank you! I was editing my question when I got your answer - my guess would be that your first equation can be understood as $\Omega^0(M,S\otimes E)\cong\Omega^0(M,S)\otimes\Omega^0(M,E)$ and the second equation can be understood as $\Omega^1(M,S\otimes E)\cong\Omega^1(M,S)\otimes\Omega^0(M,E)\cong\Omega^0(M,S)\otimes\Omega^1(M,E)$. Do you agree?

Comment: @Filippo Your claim is not true. Even for the first one, $\Omega^0(M,S\otimes E) \not \equiv \Omega^0(M,S)\otimes\Omega^0(M,E)$.

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you meant by "locally": I thought you meant "on an open subset of M", because as far as I understand, you assume that $s$ and $e$ are local frames. I admit that the equation $\Gamma(S\otimes E)\cong\Gamma(S)\otimes\Gamma(E)$ - even though it looks nice - is rather suspicious, because on the LHS, we are looking at the tensor product of two vector bundles and on the RHS, we have the tensor product of two vector spaces.

Comment: That being said, $s_i\otimes e_i\notin \Gamma(S)\otimes\Gamma(S)$ - by "locally", you meant that it's the element of $\Gamma(S\otimes E)$ defined by $(s_i\otimes e_i)(p):=s_i(p)\otimes e_i(p)$, right?

Comment: By locally, I mean that if $p \in M$ is fixed, there exists some open neighbourhood $U \ni p$ such that there exist local sections $s_i$ of $S|_U$ and $e_i$ of $E|_U$ with $\gamma|_U = \sum s_i \otimes e_i$.

Comment: Interesting - does that follow from the fact that local frames for $S$ and $E$ exist and thus $\gamma|_U=c^{ij}s_i\otimes e_j$ (we could define $\tilde{s}_j:=c^{ij}s_i$ to obtain $\gamma=\tilde{s}_j\otimes e_j$) or is that an independent result?

Comment: Yes, this can be seen that way

Comment: I thought about it and there's something I find a bit strange: I think we agree that $c^{ij}\in C^\infty(U)$ and $\gamma=\tilde{s}_i\otimes e_i=s_i\otimes\tilde{e_i}$ (where the tilde is defined as in my last comment). However, since in general $\nabla(f\Phi)\neq f\nabla(\Phi)$, I obtain $\sum_i\tilde{s}_i\otimes\nabla^Ee_i\neq\sum_i s_i\otimes\nabla^E\tilde{e}_i$, which gives me the impression that the operator $1\otimes\nabla^E$ by itself is not well defined. Is only the sum $\nabla^S\otimes 1+1\otimes\nabla^E$ well defined?

Comment: I don't get your point. Of course, $1\otimes \nabla^E$ does not respect your two writings, but so does $\nabla^S \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes \nabla^E$, recalling that a connection behaves as a derivation.

Comment: @Filippo I added a comment that explains why $\nabla$ is well defined independently of where we put your $c^{ij}$ as a coefficient.

Comment: Thank you very much! But do we agree that $\nabla^S\otimes 1$ and $1\otimes\nabla^E$ by themselves are not well defined expressions? That is, we cannot define $1\otimes\nabla^E$ by $(1\otimes\nabla^E)(\sum_i s_i\otimes e_i)=\sum_i s_i\otimes \nabla^E e_i$ (similarly for $\nabla^S\otimes 1$) because it does matter where we put the coefficients,  $\sum_i\tilde{s}_i\otimes\nabla^Ee_i\neq\sum_i s_i\otimes\nabla^E\tilde{e}_i$ - only the "sum" $\nabla^S\otimes 1+1\otimes\nabla^E$ is well defined.

Comment: Yes, we do. That is why you will never see one of these things alone by itself.