# Definition of the twisted covariant derivative

Tags: vector-bundles

I haven't found the definition online or in one of my text books, so I would appreciate a confirmation that the following definition is correct (it's supposed to be a generalization of the [twisted spin covariant derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4101799/definition-of-the-twisted-spin-covariant-derivative-for-twisted-spinor-bundles)):

For all $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, let $E_i\to M$ be a vector bundle with a covariant derivative $\nabla_i$ and consider the tensor product bundle
$$E=E_1\otimes\cdots\otimes E_n.$$
The twisted covariant derivative
\begin{equation*}
    \nabla\colon\Omega^0(M,E)\to\Omega^1(M,E)
\end{equation*}
is the unique linear function satisfying
\begin{equation*}
    \nabla(s_1\otimes\cdots\otimes s_n)=\sum_{i=1}^ns_1\otimes\cdots\otimes s_{i-1}\otimes \nabla_is_i\otimes s_{i+1}\otimes\cdots\otimes s_n
\end{equation*}
for all sections $s_i\in\Gamma(M,E_i)$.